# Can you pull objects towards you with a whip (or a similar weapon/tool)?

Tags: dnd-5e

Let's say you are a whip-wielding battle-master who makes a successful Disarming strike on an opponent, who drops his weapon to the ground. Or let's say there's an important set of keys on a table 10ft away from you and you want to get it from where you are.

In both scenarios, you would want a way to grab the desired object (fallen weapon, keys, etc.) and pull it towards you. But, although a whip (or other similar weapon/tool) would in theory be appropriate for that, I didn't see any mechanics in D&D 5e to do it.

Did I miss something ? Is there a way to grab-and-pull an object from afar (without the use of magic) ?

Comment: Related: [What check determines if a whip successfully latches onto a tree branch?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190509/what-check-determines-if-a-whip-successfully-latches-onto-a-tree-branch/190513#190513)

Answer (score 5):

## Nothing purely RAW for this

There are no mechanical properties of any current tools or items that specifically state how to grab a desired object and pull it towards you.

### But you and your DM can and should work something out

There are a lot of options here, depending on what you're trying to do. If you're a whip-wielding battle-master, then maybe you can try to 'attack' the object and follow it up with a Dex or Sleight of Hand check to try and 'grab' the object with the whip. Since there isn't a RAW ruling here, come up with something reasonable if your DM is open to this - it's a fun Indiana Jones style trick!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69339/discussion-between-nautarch-and-gael-l).

Answer (score 1):

In D&D 5e, the rules allow your character to (attempt to) do **anything you want**.

The chapter of the Players Handbook that covers combat lists a number of actions you can perform in combat. It then says that you can Improvise an Action, attempting to accomplish anything that you can think of that's not covered by the other actions listed (or found elsewhere in the book). The DM decides (with singular and absolute authority) how to resolve the action.

Yes, you can attempt to use a whip to grab some keys as an action. Your DM decides whether you succeed, fail, or roll a die.